# How to get composer to install older version of a specific dependency within required range?

Tags: composer-php

In my `composer.json` file I like to list all compatible versions of the (example) package `x/y` as possible in the `require` section. Typically that would look like `"x/y": "8-10"`. If I execute `composer install`, composer of course installs the newest available version of `x/y` which is 10.x and that is fine, almost always. But sometimes I want to install version 8 of `x/y` just to check that execution of my application is still possible with version 8.

Another scenario is when a client reports a bug and has version 2.10.4 of some `example/dependency` whereas the newest would be 2.14.2. The `example/dependency` is not required by my application directly but transitively by `x/y`. So I just for a moment want to install my whole dependency tree with version 2.10.4 of `example/dependency` to debug it with that version of the library.

Of course a temporary modification of the `composer.json` so that it requires these exact versions would work but that approach seems unnatural, complex, and implies the risk of accidentally committing the modified `composer.json` to version control and thereby creating a huge mess.

I thought about modifying the `composer.lock` because accidentally committing a modified version of that wouldn't really cause a problem. But is it okay/recommended to modify the `composer.lock` file for such purposes?

Ideally I would want a command line argument that fixes some library to some version just for one execution of the `composer install` command without modifying `composer.json`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `install` is meant to read from a lockfile, this option wouldn't make sense for the command.

But for `update` (and if there is no lockfile, `install` behaves as `update`), there is the `--prefer-lowest` flag ([docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u)).

There is also the option to downgrade a specific package without affecting your `composer.json` file, by running something like:

```
composer update --with vendor/package:2.0.1
```

Mind you, any of these options **will** modify your lockfile, so after testing you would probably need to `git restore composer.lock` to go back to the original state.

Commiting a lockfile for a project by mistake **should** be a biggish issue. Since applications are usually built/deployed by reading the lockfile, a lockfile in an inconsistent state could break things in unexpected places.

But warding of commiting and pushing changes by mistake seems to be excessive, IMO. Developers can make changes to **any** file, and if they commit those "by mistake", things can break all around.

Expecting a basic "I should look what's changed before staging and commiting" seems a very low bar to me.

Comment: Thanks! There are lots of metaphorical gems for me to collect in your answer.